# React: save ref to state in a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I want to create a ref to an element, save it in state and use it somewhere else, down the line. Here is what I have so far:

```js
const Header = () => {
  const topElement = useRef();
  const { setRootElement } = useScrollToTop();

  useEffect(() => {
    setRootElement(topElement);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={topElement}>
     ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `useScrollToTop` hook:

```js
export const useScrollToTop = () => {
  const [rootElement, setRootElement] = useState();

  const scrollToTop = () => {
    rootElement.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  return {
    scrollToTop: scrollToTop,
    setRootElement: setRootElement
  };
};
```

And in a different component:

```js
const LongList = () => {

    const { scrollToTop } = useScrollToTop();

    return (
       <div>
        ....
          <button onClick={() => scrollToTop()} />
       </div>
    );
}
```

The `setRootElemet` works okay, it saves the element that I pass to it but when I call `scrollToTop()` the element is undefined. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

As hooks are essentially just functions, there is no state shared between calls. Each time you call `useScrollToTop` you are getting a new object with its own `scrollToTop` and `setRootElement`. When you call `useScrollToTop` in `LongList`, the returned `setRootElement` is never used and therefore that instance `rootElement` will never have a value.

What you need to do is have one call to `useScrollToTop` and pass the returned items to their respective components. Also, instead of using a state in the hook for the element, you can use a ref directly and return it.

Putting these together, assuming you have an App structure something like:

- App

  - Header
  - LongList

**Hook:**

```
export const useScrollToTop = () => {
  const rootElement = useRef();

  const scrollToTop = () => {
    rootElement.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  return {
    scrollToTop,
    rootElement,
  };
};
```

**App:**

```
...
const { scrollToTop, rootElement } = useScrollToTop();

return (
  ...
  <Header rootElementRef={rootElement} />
  <LongList scrollToTop={scrollToTop} />
  ...
);
```

**Header:**

```
const Header = ({ rootElementRef }) => {
  return (
    <div ref={rootElementRef}>
     ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

**LongList:**

```
const LongList = ({ scrollToTop }) => {
  return (
    <div>
    ...
      <button onClick={() => scrollToTop()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably is `topElement` would be null initially and useEffect would trigger `setRootElement` with null. You would need to keep `topElement` in state variable and check when it changes and set the value inside your JSX as

```
const [topElement, setTopElement] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {topElement && setRootElement(topElement);}, [topElement])

return (
    <div ref={(ref) => setTopElement(ref)}>
         ...
    </div>
);
```